# Batch file to Copy the last n lines of a text file into a new text file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

is there a way using a batch file to copy the last n lines of a log file into a new  text file.

Log file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

n = 2

Newfile:

```
line 4
line 5
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your coding attempts; consult this help topic: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```cmd
@echo off
set /A "_LAST=2" & rem // (define the number of last lines to keep)
for /F %%C in ('^< "test.log" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
set /A "LINES=COUNT-_LAST"
if %LINES% gtr 0 (set "SKIP=+%LINES%") else (set "SKIP=")
> "test.log.new" more %SKIP% "test.log"
```

This script can handle log files containing empty lines and such with a length of up to 65534 characters. However, the output file must not contain more than 65535 lines. Note, that <kbd>TABs</kbd> become expanded to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>.

---

Or try this:

```cmd
@echo off
set /A "_LAST=2" & rem // (define the number of last lines to keep)
for /F %%C in ('^< "test.log" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
set /A "LINES=COUNT-_LAST"
if %LINES% gtr 0 (set "SKIP=skip^=%LINES%") else (set "SKIP=")
> "test.log.new" (
    for /F usebackq^ %SKIP%^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("test.log") do (
        echo(%%L
    )
)
```

This one has not got a limitation for the number of lines, though the file size must be less than 2 GiB. However, it cannot handle files containing empty lines (as they get lost) and such with a length of more than 8190 characters.